# Automatically add new wireless access points

Tags: network-manager, wireless, xfce

I'm running Lucid on a few laptops, with xfce as the desktop environment.

Before Lucid, the little NetworkManager tray widget would automatically scan for access points for me. Now, however, I find that I have to go run `iwlist` myself to look for SSIDs (if I don't know one already) and manually add that to the list. Once I've done that, then it'll automatically connect (if the AP is configured that way).

Part of what makes this a real pain is that the tray widget (sometimes) seems to not show itself at all when there's no current connection and no known access points. I have to kill NetworkManager (which is a pain, because `init` really wants to re-launch it), run `iwlist` to find an SSID, go to the (now showing) tray widget and add the SSID, and then re-start NetworkManager.

I realize that the widget is just messing with a config file or two, and I'm happy to fool with those manually, but what I'd *really* like is for it to work the way it used to and just do the scan for me. Note that once I've got a connection up, *then* it shows me all the APs it can see, as before.

I acknowledge that it's possible I screwed up some setup file, but I've really tried scrubbing everything back to "as new" state and that hasn't helped.  Am I crazy or did that stuff really change?

Comment: [etckeeper](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=etckeeper) can help with finding out what config settings changed and when (but only for /etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask upstart (the init daemon used on Ubuntu) to stop NetworkManager, that's much "cleaner" than killing the process yourself: `sudo initctl stop network-manager` (replace "stop" with "start" to start it manually again).

About the issues with NetworkManager: it seems like it logs to `/var/log/daemon.log`; maybe you can find some useful messages there?

Comment: I know everything is moving (or is moved) to upstart, but is there anything wrong with using `sudo service NetworkManager stop`?

Comment: When there is a script in `/etc/init.d/`  that does the "initctl" for you (and it's there for network-manager), `service` will work too.  (But note that it's called "network-manager" now, not "NetworkManager" as it was called in the past IIRC.)

Comment: It's still called "NetworkManager" in 10.04. Thanks for the suggestions, but my problem isn't so much with how to go about killing/restarting NetworkManager.  I'd rather not have to do it at all :-)

Comment: I have *no* init script named "NetworkManager" in 10.04 (and everything works fine here...).  And to fix your issue, please check the logfile(s) I mention above if they have any useful info.

Comment: Aparently the package is called "network-manager", and it include /etc/init.d/NetworkManager - maybe you don't have it installed. When I log in when not near any known access points, the tray widget hides itself and makes it impossible to select from any AP's it may have scanned. There's stuff in the log file, but it's not very clear what it means.

Comment: Well, `dpkg -L network-manager | grep /etc/init.d/` outputs `/etc/init.d/network-manager`...

Comment: Maybe you should try to reinstall network-manager and see if that fixes anything?